# How to use JavaScript Math.random() within HTML p tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print 1 random number within my `<p>` in HTML.

JavaScript:

```js
function number() 
{
    var minNumber = 1; // The minimum number you want 
    var maxNumber = 5; // The maximum number you want
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number

    document.getElementById("randomNum").innerHTML = randomNumber; // Sets content of <div> to number

    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}

window.onload = number; // Runs the function on click
```

HTML:

```html
<div class = card>
  <div id="randomNum">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>stats - [randomNumber] <br/> stat 2 - [randomNumber] </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I could not get my HTML to post normally so I had to make it ugly. Sorry...)

My random number will print off to the side, and it is unable to print more within the same p. I was wondering if there is a way to place my random number from JavaScript within my p in HTML and keep all the css settings within the other div class card.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried fixing your code formatting, but I'm really not sure what you intended to put in the HTML example

Comment: Your question formatting has been fixed. Do you think you could double-check the HTML part? FYI, sounds like you want `document.querySelector("#randomNum p").textContent = randomNumber`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to place the random number in the `p` instead of the `div`, and have it append each time.

You should create an element each time with `document.createElement` and append it to the div, like this

```
function number() 
{
    var minNumber = 1; // The minimum number you want 
    var maxNumber = 5; // The maximum number you want
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number

    var newNumber = document.createElement("p");
    newNumber.innerText = randomNumber;

    document.getElementById("randomNum").appendChild(newNumber);

    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}
```

Comment: What would be the formatting when adding this to my p tag? Would var newNumber, allow that to work in any p tag?

Comment: This will add a new P tag into your div each time you run it, containing the number.

Comment: so every time my p tag is being used in my HTML file the random number will be in there automatically with this javascript function?

Comment: No. Each time you run the function, it creates a new P tag with the number and adds it to the div.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function number() 
{
    var minNumber = 1; // The minimum number you want 
    var maxNumber = 5; // The maximum number you want
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number

    //document.getElementById("randomNum").innerHTML = randomNumber; // Sets content of <div> to number
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("randNum");
    x[0].innerHTML = randomNumber;
    x[1].innerHTML = randomNumber;

    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}

window.onload = number; // Runs the function on click
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class = card>
  <div id="randomNum">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>stats - <span class="randNum"></span> <br/> stat 2 - <span class="randNum"></span> </p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works but the random number only prints once and it is not within the same line as stats, it prints in the middle of the circle I have from my css file. Is this something I would have to correct within my CSS file? or would it be a javascript issue?

Comment: You have got a break tag inside the p element which you have to remove to keep the random number in the same line.

Comment: <p>stats - <span class="randNum"></span> stat 2 - <span class="randNum"></span> stats - <span class="randNum"></span></p>

Comment: Also if you use for loop and you can display any numbers of random number using the class name for the span element within the p element e.g.

Comment: for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
     x[i].innerHTML = randomNumber;
    }

Comment: Also, if you don't want to change your CSS file you could just use inline CSS inside the p element e.g. <p style="..."> ... </p>

Answer (score -2):

You have to give the P element a ID, then do a `document.getElementbyID(whatever you put the ID for in the P tag) = randomNumber` Your Html should be

```
<p id="whatever you want"></p>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: `window.onload` does indeed _"work like that"_